# Checkbox on related list

Tags: custom-object, customsetting, customization

Does anyone know how to add the checkbox column on related list in SF? I have a custom object that I'm try to get checkboxes for related list. Thanks

[image: Without checkbox]

[image: With checkboxes]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add a custom list button to the custom object, and choose the "Show boxes for selection" box underneath the button type. When you add the button to the related list or list view, it will enable the checkboxes.

Comment: how to add such checkboxes in lightning experience?

Comment: in Lightning experience, you will have to click "View All". Not an ideal solution because the button is still visible on related list. If there was setting to show the button on "View All" screen, it would still have been OK.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Screenshot of where in the button creation you select to show the check-box for the records created as related list items in the parent record.